# How to write a list of data in excel in column wise using Java?

Tags: java, excel, arraylist, apache-poi, xssf

I have a list of data in `ArrayList` which contains the heading as well as the values associated with it. Like below,

```
Fruits 
Apple 
Orange 
******
Vegetables 
Beans
Carrot 
Brinjal
Cucumber 
******
Colors
Orange 
Blue
Red
Green
Yellow

Now, I want to write the values in `excel` with each heading and the associated values in column-wise. Like below,

Fruits   Vegetable   Colors
Apple    Beans       Orange 
Orange   Carrot      Blue
         Brinjal     Red
         Cucumber    Green
                     Yellow
```

I'm writing my code in java and using `apache.poi.xssf.usermodel` library, to handing the `excel` manipulations. The issue what I'm facing here is, when I'm writing the 2nd heading and the associated values, the first heading and its values are getting cleared due to the `Row` creation code

```
XSSFRow row = outputSheet.createRow(rowNumValue);
```

Can anyone help me get this done?

Comment: Split, get the first String and make it the cat and after that loop the items and put it into a String Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could operate immediately on the single list, but it is easier to use a sensible data structure. As every column can have a different number of rows, **make a list of columns, every column a list of rows**.

```
List<List<String>> makeColumns(List<String> linearList) {
    List<List<String>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
    int column = 0;
    for (String s : linearList) {
        if (s.startsWith("***")) {
            ++column;
        } else {
            while (column >= columns.size()) {
                columns.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }
            columns.get(column).add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Now one can iterate over the rows to fill the sheet.

```
List<List<String>> columns = makeColumns(...);
int rows = columns.stream().mapToInt(List::size).max().orElse(0);

for (int rowi = 0; rowi < rows; ++rowi) {
    XSSFRow row = outputSheet.createRow(rowi + 1);
    for (int coli = 0; coli < columns.size(); ++coli) {
        if (rowi < columns.get(coli).size()) {
            String value = columns.get(coli).get(rowi);
            row.createCell(coli);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is use `createRow()` the first time to... create the row, and `getRow()` for all subsequent access. That way, you'll get the row already in the worksheet object instead of creating a new one. `getRow()` returns null if the row doesn't exist, so you can do the equivalent of this:

```
XSSFRow row = outputSheet.getRow(rowNumValue) ? outputSheet.getRow(rowNumValue) : outputSheet.createRow(rowNumValue);
```